boto3 GetSecretValue Access to KMS is not allowed
I'm trying to get an AWS Secret Manager secret through the API on my laptop and I get:
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling 
the GetSecretValue operation: Access to KMS is not allowed

I have an administrator account on AWS so I should be able to access the KMS or am I mistaken ?
Here's the code I'm using:
import boto3
client = boto3.client("secretsmanager", region_name = "eu-west-1")
client.get_secret_value(SecretId="rds_secret")

The output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
client.get_secret_value(SecretId="rds_secret")
File "/home/julien/Documents/cloud-tools/lib/python3.11/site- 
packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/julien/Documents/cloud-tools/lib/python3.11/site- 
packages/botocore/client.py", line 1009, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred 
(AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue 
operation: Access to KMS is not allowed

sts calle-identity returns my ARN user account with the right access-key and account number.
Here's the KMS Key policy:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "auto-secretsmanager-2",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow access through AWS Secrets Manager for all principals in the account that are authorized to use AWS Secrets Manager",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "kms:CallerAccount": "<account-number>",
                "kms:ViaService": "secretsmanager.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow access through AWS Secrets Manager for all principals in the account that are authorized to use AWS Secrets Manager",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "kms:CallerAccount": "<account-number>"
            },
            "StringLike": {
                "kms:ViaService": 
"secretsmanager.*.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow direct access to key metadata to the account",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-number>:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Describe*",
            "kms:Get*",
            "kms:List*",
            "kms:RevokeGrant"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}


Check which IAM role you are actually using, with aws sts get-caller-identity (or the boto3 equivalent call). Also, what is in the KMS key policy?

I have updated my question with the requested info. Thanks for your time !

Related troubleshooting here.

I have checked the provided link. I'm not in the case of cross-accounts. I'm using a key with the permissions given to the user I'm using in the same account.

If you don't have access to access to the KMS key that is used to encrypt the secret's manager, then you will get this error.
Make sure to update the policy of the role/profile you're using with the following,
   {
      "Sid": "Allow access to KMS",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
                "kms:GetParametersForImport",
                "kms:DescribeCustomKeyStores",
                "kms:ListKeys",
                "kms:GetPublicKey",
                "kms:ListKeyPolicies",
                "kms:ListRetirableGrants",
                "kms:GetKeyRotationStatus",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "kms:GetKeyPolicy",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:ListResourceTags",
                "kms:ListGrants"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "kms:CallerAccount": "<account-number>",
          "kms:ViaService": "secretsmanager.<your-region>.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    }


Go to the Secrets Manager
Select the Secret and Click Edit Encryption key to see the Encryption KMS
Then open the KMS Key and update the following to the KMS Key policy,

        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<destination-account-number>:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },


Hi, many thanks for taking time to help me. I have attached the policy to my user but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

You need to probably update the KMS key policy too. I updated the answer

The secret is encrypted using a custom KMS key. The key policy is already updated with my user info and I'm already able to use it with Lambda for instance. But I get the below error when trying to get the secret value.

Could you please edit the question with the command you use

I have just done the edit
